Magento 2 : How Can I disable woff2 format?
How can I disable woff2 format for fonts in Magento 2?
I need .lib-font-face to connect only woff.

@WhoYou
Hey,
You can edit the woff2 font format to woff by change/edit theme's or custom font css file.
Like go to css file where @font-face {} is used than just remove woff2 line than just simple woff is loaded.
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Font-Name';
    src: ('../font file path/Font.woff) format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
}

Than clear cache. (if effect not occurred than run static content deploy command)
Thank You!

To disable the woff2 format and use only woff in Magento 2, you need to override the _typography.less file where the @font-face is defined. Here are the steps:

Create a new _typography.less file in your theme directory. The path should be like this: app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/css/source/_typography.less.

In this file, redefine the .lib-font-face mixin to exclude the woff2 format. Here's an example:


.lib-font-face(
    @family-name,
    @font-path,
    @font-weight: 400,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: swap
) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: @family-name;
        src: url('@{font-path}.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: @font-weight;
        font-style: @font-style;
        font-display: @font-display;
    }
}


After saving the file, you need to clear the cache and deploy static content. You can do this by running the following commands in the terminal:

php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

This will make Magento 2 use only the woff format for fonts.
